# How to create a route with python and flask based on user input?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, rest

I am using python with flask as a backend and I am trying to create a route to a table in my database based on user input. During one of my post requests a table is created in the database. I then want to create a connection to this table. The table name also depends on user input. I want to emphasize that I am able to create the tables in the database based on user input and now need to create the route to these tables.
Is there a way to create such route?
I understand that doing something like this may lead to security vulnerability so I am open to suggestions for different approaches.

I am attaching below my current python code for creating routes:

```
# Destination Class/model
class Destinations(db.Model):
    ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    city = db.Column(db.String(100))
    country = db.Column(db.String(100))

    def __init__(self, city, country):
        self.city = city
        self.country = country

# Destinations Schema
class DestinationsSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('ID', 'city', 'country')

# Init Destinations Schema
destination_schema = DestinationsSchema()
destinations_schema = DestinationsSchema(many=True)

# Create a Destination
@app.route('/destinations', methods=['POST'])
def add_destination():
    city = request.json['city']
    country = request.json['country']

    new_destination = Destinations(city, country)

    db.session.add(new_destination)
    db.session.commit()

    return destination_schema.jsonify(new_destination)

# Get All Destinations
@app.route('/destinations', methods=['GET'])
def get_destinations():
    all_destinations = Destinations.query.all()
    result = destinations_schema.dump(all_destinations)
    return jsonify(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer to what I understood from your question. I hope it helps you:

You can put a variable in the url. Something like this:

```
 @app.route('/destinations/<tablename>', methods=['GET'])
 def get_destination(tablename):
        destination = Destinations.query.filter_by(name=tablename)
        result = destinations_schema.dump(destination )
        return jsonify(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Won't this just change the name of the table when I try to access it with my frontend, but eventually just access the same table in the database? Based on user input I'm creating more tables that look like the "destinations" table and I want to create a route to these tables.

Comment: I adjusted my answer. I hope this is what you are looking for.